# Difference between Lists

Tags: sorting

You are given 2 lists, the first with a elements and the second with b elements, with a < b.

For each element e in list a, you want to take a element f in list b, and replace e with e-f. You cannot use a element twice unless it appears in list b twice.

The problem is to find the minimum value of the largest element of list a.

For example, say list a is [1, 2, 3, 4], and list b is [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]. We would take the e's to be 5, 6, 7, 8, so that list a becomes [5-1, 6-2, 7-3, 8-4], with the largest element being 4. So 4 is the answer.

Another example: if list a is [1, 4, 7] and list b is [-1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], we would take the e's to be -1, 4, 7, so that list a becomes [2, 0, 0], and the answer is 2. So 2 is the answer.

I know this is poorly worded, if I could do anything to better word it, please let me know. I tried first sorting list a and list b, then did not know what to do.

If you could help, please do.

Thanks!

Comment: Would you like us to solve your interview question/homework for you?

Comment: This is not an interview question/homework. I was just curious about whether or not there is an algorithm for this.

Answer (score 0):

1. calculate the values of the list:
   (java)

   List listA = ...;

   List listb = ...;

   for(int i = 0; i < listA.size(); i++){

   ```
   listA.set(i, listA.get(i) - listb.get(i));
   ```

   }
2. find the highest value in listA:

   iHighestValue = listA.get(0); //setting it to 0 would not work with lists containing only negative integers

   for(int j = 1; j < listA.size(); j++){

   ```
   if(listA.get(j) > iHighestValue)

       iHighestValue = listA.get(i);
   ```

   }
   [Edit]: sorry, it doesn't show as code (don't know why)